# How to have all the images in a folder stacked on top of each other in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a folder that contains nothing but images named 1.jpg - 484.jpg. Is there a simple way to have all the images stacked on top each other in one long image in ffmpeg? (preferably with one command)

I've searched for this thing a bunch of times but I haven't found the answer I was looking for. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If needing ffmpeg, the `vstack` filter complex is useful.  This example uses vstack to iterate in a directory (with even number of files in the subsets and a one pixel high blank buffer 000.jpg).

```sh
prev=src/000.jpg; i=0; odd=1; num=0; for file in src/*; do num=$(($num+1)) && if [ $odd == "-1" ]; then ffmpeg -i $prev -i $file -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]vstack[s]" -map "[s]" -y out/0output$i.jpg; fi && odd=$(($odd*-1)); prev=$file && i=$(($i+1)); done; sets=$(echo "scale=0;sqrt($num)"|bc); n=0; for (( a=0; a<sets ; a++ )); do prev=src/000.jpg && i=0 && n=$(($n+1)) && odd=1 && for file in out/"$(($n-1))"output*.jpg; do if [ $odd == "-1" ]; then ffmpeg -i $prev -i $file -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]vstack[s]" -map "[s]" -y out/"$n"output$i.jpg; fi && prev=$file && i=$(($i+1)) && odd=$(($odd*-1)); done; done;
```

Given inputs: [image] ,[image],etc

Yielding:

[image: Five image stack with ffmpeg]

Comment: I ran this under Pop!os bash, wsl ubuntu, and cmd and all of them would give me an error. The linux errors were `Could not open file : out/0output483.jpg av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error` the `out/0output483.jpg` part would change depending on what image it was on.

Comment: Im unsure but this particular example algorithm errors when the subsets have an odd number of frames.